# A usage of infinitive clause which doesn't refer to "a noun" and doesn't specify "a purpose". What is that?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, adverbial-phrases

Today, I saw a different usage of infinitive clauses at the university and would like to ask you it in order to be familiar with that usage.(Examples from my professor)

> There should be more than 100 people at the party **to have fun.**(1)

The intended meaning: "**What is needed to have fun is more than 100 people at the party. So, a party including less than 100 people is not good to have fun**."

> A few good opportunities exist **to go to the U.S**.(2)

The intended meaning: "**A few good opportunities exist if you want to go to the U.S**"

(My professor said that we don't need to say:"A few good opportunities to go to the U.S exist". This also works)

> **To be able to study at that university**, you have many problems. First of all, you have to solve them and then you can go.(3)

The intended meaning: "**You have more problems than you can have at that university while studying there**."

So, as you can see, those infinitive clauses don't specify any "purpose", don't define any nouns and are not subjects, however, they function as adverbials.

So these usages are very different for me because I always see a purpose when an infinitive clause is an adverbial but here, there is no purpose/reason even if it is adverbial.

Could you please tell me what its function is exactly? and do you find those usages natural/correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Idiomatically, you can (just about) say *You have **too many** problems to go to university*, but in that construction you can't "front" the [infinitive clause](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm) (and I don't see how you can avoid including something like ***too*** there). As you can see from examples in that link, infinitive clauses can convey many other things besides "purpose".

Comment: This sentence is not grammatical: "So, a party including less than 100 people is not good to have fun."  You must say "not good *enough* to have fun".

Comment: This sentence is also not grammatical: *To be able to study at that university, you have many problems*.   You must say something like *To be able to study at that university, **you must first solve many problems**.*  (or *must overcome certain obstacles.*) When the meaning is "in order to {do x}", the main clause must state the thing that *enables*, not a thing that *prevents*.   *To fly, you must have wings.*  **You must have wings to fly.**

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo this idea is going to the way rejecting the second example as well.
Because "to go to the U.S" doesn't specify any purpose or state the thing that enables..

Comment: In #2, there the infinitive clause complements **opportunities**.

Comment: But they are separated from each other. How can the infinitive clause refer to opportunities? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: **Some good opportunities** exist for [ing] does not mean **Few good opportunities** exist for[ verb +i ng]. If you use a few, I suggest using it like this:   "A few good opportunities **do exist** for [ing verb].

Comment: @Lambie I agree with you on it. How about the function of "to go to the U.S" ? What do you think about it? I don't think that it refers to "opportunities" because it is used after the main verb "exist". If it was intended to refer to "opportunities", it would be used just after "opportunities" but in that way, it doesn't refer to "opportunities", which means that it functions as an adverbial. Do you agree?

Comment: @Jawel: not to go, here. **X opportunities exist for going to the U.S.** Here, I would avoid to and use for. I think the focus is more on going, than anything else....If you say to, the focus is  not on the fact of going. Does that make sense?